# How I refuse a request of my friend to give my laptop?

Tags: friends

My question is about the one of my friend. She want to buy a laptop as I have two laptop. One for the university use and one for my home use. She ask me to buy my another laptop as I said I have my personal data on that laptop, So I don't want to give her. How I refuse a request of my friend to give my laptop?

Comment: What makes you think you can't simply say "no, I need both laptops"?

Comment: What did she said when you said you have personal data on the "home use" one? why she want to buy one from you? does she thinks it will be cheaper than any other used laptop?

Comment: Hello and welcome to IPS! You might find [this meta post](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) on writing questions helpful. Could you add some info about the relationship between you and the friend, how close are you, do you have reason to be worried that she won't take a simple "no" for an answer? Your ages and cultural context may be useful to add as well.

Comment: I assume English is not your first language.  Give and buy are not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is by itself pretty simple and the answer is also pretty simple.  She wants to buy a laptop from you.  Is it for sale?  If not, then the response is also quite simple: "it's not for sale".

If there are other issues that we need to be concerned with, they should be included in the question.  If she wants you to give her a laptop, the answer is also similar: "I'm not giving away my laptop".  Whatever response she makes to either answer, merely repeat your response.  Eventually she'll realize that she has no claim on your property.

And if you lose her as a friend over this, good riddance.  Real friends don't demand things from their friends and then refuse to accept "no" as an answer.